# Switch and If Else Combined

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, logical-operators

I'm wondering about this program? Is it possible that if else and switch can be combined? I think that may be the reason why the last part of the program can't run aside from the occurring error if the logical OR wasn't removed from the codes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int houseType;
    int hourHome;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please select your type of residence: ");
    System.out.println("Press 1 for an apartment");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for a house");
    System.out.println("Press 3 for a dormitory");
    houseType = input.nextInt();

    switch (houseType) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You entered you reside in an apartment");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You entered you reside in a house");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You entered you reside in a dormitory");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid selection");
            break;
    }
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please select the average number of hours you're home per day ");
    System.out.println("Press 1 for 18 hours or more");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for 10 to 17 hours");
    System.out.println("Press 3 for 8 to 9 hours");
    System.out.println("Press 4 for 6 to 7 hours");
    System.out.println("Press 5 for 0 to 5 hours");
    hourHome = input.nextInt();

    switch (hourHome) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You entered you are home for 18 hours per day or more");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("You entered you are home between 10 and 17" +
                    "hours per day");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You entered you are home between 8 and 9 hours per day");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("You entered you are home between 6 and 7 hours per day");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("You entered you are home between 0 and 5 hours per day");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("You have entered an invalid selection");
            break;
    }
    if (houseType == 1 && hourHome == 1) {
        System.out.println("Based on your selections, it's recommended you get pot-bellied pig");
    } else if (houseType == 1 && hourHome == 2) {
        System.out.println("Based on your selections, it's recommended you get a dog");
    } else

        if (houseType == 1 && ((hourHome == 3 || 4 || 5)) {
            System.out.println("Based on your selections, it's recommended you get a snake");

        }
}
```

Comment: You can nest if/else in switch or switch in if/else without problems. So you will have to keep looking for the issue :)

Comment: Also don't open multiple scanners on a single input stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to change few things in your code

change:

```
hourHome = input.nextInt();
```

to:

```
hourHome = input2.nextInt();
```

change:

```
(hourHome == 3 || 4 || 5)
```

to:

```
else if (houseType == 1 && ((hourHome == 3 || hourHome == 4 || hourHome    == 5))){
```

And yes you can nest if/else in switch statement.

You can also use single Scanner for both hourHome and houseType

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't with using both switch statements and if statements. There is nothing wrong with that.

You have an error here:

```
(hourHome == 3 || 4 || 5)
```

`4` and `5` are not boolean expressions and can't be used like that. You probably meant:

```
(hourHome == 3 || hourHome == 4 || hourHome == 5)
```